# i am getting this error: IndexError: list index out of range. I dont know how to correct it

Tags: web.py

I am learning programming. To practice I tried to write a program for reversing the list. But I am getting error in 13th line. So please help. Thanks.

```
a = [int(x) for x in input("Enter list:").split()]
i=0
for a[i] in a:
    if(a[i:]==[]):
        break
    i=i+1
    #print("",i)
n=i
print("total terms in the sequence-",n)
i=0
while(i<=n):
    temp=a[i]
    a[i]=a[n-i]
    a[n-i]=temp
    i=i+1
print("",a)
```

Comment: I've flagged this as off-topic on the grounds that your problem is caused by a typo, so solving it wouldn't be useful to others. That said, replacing `i<=n` with `i<n` should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is because n is outside of the index of your array.

For example if a list has 4 elements. n = 4 but when you call a[n(4)] this doesnt work because an array is 0 indexed meaning the first element in an array with 4 items is a[0] and the last element is a[3]